# Does GTA V DRM prevent you from family sharing it on Steam?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, steam-family-sharing

Is there any way to get GTA 5 on family sharing? The CD key is tied to the Steam account.

Answer (score 1):

As the game runs with Rockstar Social Club DRM, this isn't possible.

Comment: Any citation for that info?

Comment: @Andrew you can verify the info by booting up the game.